# ASP.NET on ubuntu

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux

I am waiting on my windows 7 to arrive and I am forced to use Ubuntu for the time being. I have tried using mono-project but I can't seem to find where to actually run and display my web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development purposes you can use XSP to quickly run up a server and browse pages.  Easiest way is to start it from the root directory of your application.

Check out [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) for details.

A quick excerpt if you want to get up and running *now*:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/xsp/test
$ xsp
Listening on port: 8080
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /home/cvs/mcs/class/corlib/Microsoft.Win32
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is intended to run on iis.  So under linux, you need to use a special server.  There's mod_mono for Apache or XSP (a C# based web server).  Those are the only two linux servers that support Mono to my knowledge.